# How I can return all fields from procedure?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Now I have the following procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_city_by_name(match varchar) RETURNS TABLE(city_name varchar) LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$

        BEGIN
                RETURN QUERY WITH r AS (
                        SELECT short_name FROM geo_cities WHERE short_name ILIKE CONCAT(match, '%')
                )
                SELECT r.short_name FROM r;
        END;

$$
```

I want return all fields (`*`) (not only `short_name`). What I need to change in my procedure?

Comment: How do you call the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified (w/o `WITH` and with `language sql`) version, that I've mentioned in my comment to the adjacent answer:

```
create or replace function find_city_by_name(text)
  returns table(city_name varchar, long_name varchar)
as $$
  select * from geo_cities where short_name ilike $1 || '%';
$$ language sql;
```

Also, you might find it more convenient to refer to the `geo_cities` table itself defining the function's signature, using `SETOF geo_cities`:

```
create or replace function find_city_by_name(text)
  returns setof geo_cities
as $$
  select * from geo_cities where short_name ilike $1 || '%';
$$ language sql;
```

-- this will allow you to change the structure of `geo_cities` table w/o necessity to change the function's definition.

Comment: `setof geo_cities` is what I need, because I dont want to declare explicit all fields in the return clause. thanks for your answer)

Comment: `setof geo_cities` doesn't help me if I add `inner join` to my function. How can I change the return clause in this case? I mean something of `returns table(*)`

Comment: In this case, you need to enlist columns explicitly. Two another options (going beyond of what we touched here): a) `create view v1 as select ... join ...` and then `setof v1`, but ALTERing tables will be painful; b) explore Postgres' "NoSQL/schemaless" power – JSONB data type, work with it, return JSON data from your function, this will give you more freedom and flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a real row you must to explicit declare all fields in the return clausule:

```
create table geo_cities (
    short_name varchar,
    long_name varchar
);

insert into geo_cities values ('BERLIN', 'BERLIN'), ('BERLIN 2','BERLIN TWO');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_city_by_name(match varchar) 
    RETURNS TABLE(city_name varchar, long_name varchar) 
    LANGUAGE plpgsql 
AS 
$$
    BEGIN
            RETURN QUERY WITH r AS (
                    SELECT * FROM geo_cities WHERE short_name ILIKE CONCAT(match, '%')
            )
            SELECT * FROM r;
    END;
$$;

select * from find_city_by_name('BERLIN');
```

See the example running at: http://rextester.com/IKTT52978

Comment: I'd also notice that plpgsql is not really needed here. This function can easily be defined using `language sql` and definition will be shorter. `WITH` here also looks like smth that is not really needed.

Comment: Yes. But I supouse that the procedure is an example of something more complex. In that case the important part is `returns table(city_name varchar, long_name varchar)`